# Java: Loading data from a file located under project folder fails

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to read a `.yaml` file (which is located under my project folder, **not** under the same package with the java file below) by using the [org.yaml.snake](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml) library.

My java source file is as follows:

**sample.java**

```
private void readAndLoadFromConfigFile() {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.yaml");
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Map<String, String>> values = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) yaml.load(inputStream);
            for (String key : values.keySet()) {
                Map<String, String> subValues = values.get(key);
                logger.info(key);

                for (String subValueKey : subValues.keySet()) {
                    logger.info(String.format("\t%s = %s", subValueKey, subValues.get(subValueKey)));
                }
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and **config.yaml** is:

```
ip_addresses:
firstMachineAddress : '162.242.195.82'
secondMachineAddress : '50.31.209.229'
ports:
firstTargetPort : '4041'
secondTargetPort : '5051'
```

However I get "stream closed" exception. Could anyone spot the problem?

**EDIT:** I added `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and now it says `file not found`, which is a different problem. I suspect the error to be a path issue, that it cannot find my `config.yaml`.

Anyone could give an idea about how to refer to a file under the project folder?

Comment: Check the yml.load method, it might already close the stream you pass to it. This might lead you to try to close an already closed stream.

Comment: That comes with the library, it's not my method. How can I check it?

Comment: Depends on your IDE, in Intellij you can Ctrl+click the load method to view/download the sources. You could also try to set a debug point on inputStream.close and check if the stream is already closed before the method is called. You could also comment out the inputStream.close() line and see if the same error occurs.

Comment: If it's in root of you project, maybe try using absolute path: `\config.yaml` ?

Comment: It works only when I give the full absolute path string, which is not okay. There should be a way to do this, Java cannot be this limited. As for your request @yariash, 

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /config.yaml (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Your yml file should be inside the src/main/resources folder instead of the root of your project

Comment: I don't have main and resources folders, I have several packages, build, pom.xml and that's about it. So, isn't there a way to reference this apart from giving the full absolute path?

Comment: Create the src/main/resources folder then. Since you use maven you should also apply its standard directory layout: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll create the folder structure and try calling it again.

Comment: Even after creating main/resources, I still get the error saying it was not found. Isn't this how I should use ? `InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/config.yaml"));`

Comment: I think it should be as follows: inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.yaml");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the path right.

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("...")` loads a file relative to the path the current class is located in (because you use the class to query the resource). Thus, if your class is located in a package named `com.example.mypackage` and you give a string `"config.yaml"`, that file is searched *relative to the class' package folder*.

Since you use maven, the proper way to place the file would be in `src/main/resources/com/example/mypackage/config.yaml`. If, however, you want to have the yaml file lying directly in `src/main/resources`, you have to use the *absolute* path `"/config.yaml"` (*absolute* in the context of your JAR, that is).

Or, probably cleaner, use the class loader for querying a relative path:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.yaml");
```

This will will with config.yaml in `src/main/resources`.